# SQL query to Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have the following SQLite query, which is the ActiveRecord equivalent?

My main goal here is to build a clients table with a validation of how many sales of the client are over 29 days of antiquity. Any help is appreciated guys.

```
select
    clients.id,
    clients.razon,
    clients.rfc,
    clients.state,
    clients.city,
    count(sales.id) AS "Num sales",
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN (
            (julianday('now') - julianday(sales.created_at) > 29)
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS outdated_sales
from clients
join sales
    where clients.id = sales.client_id
    and sales.sku != ""
GROUP by sales.client_id
ORDER BY sales.created_at asc;
```

Comment: Edit your question and the rails code that isn't executing the query, and any error messages you are seeing. Please, no screen shots or images....

Comment: How does your code look so far? How do your models look like? How did you define the association between clients and sales in your models?

Comment: When I run the query on "DB Browser for SQLite" Windows app, the code runs fine, but when I try to run it in my Rails app it throws a ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error, that's why I'm searching if there is a ActiveRecord equivalent to this query.

Comment: My main goal is to build a clients table with a validation of how many sales of the client are over 29 days of antiquity.

Comment: Why is there a mysql tag here? The date criteria should be part of the WHERE criteria. `sales.created_at < (julianday('now') - 29)` maybe.

Comment: I don't want to exclude the sales that are not over 29 days, I would like just to count them in a column.

Answer (score 1):

Below could be an equivalent ruby query for the given sql query.

```
Client.joins(:sales)
  .where("clients.id == sales.client_id AND sales.sku IS NOT IN (?)", ["", nil])
  .select("id, razon, rfc, state, city, count(sales.id) as num_sales")
  .order("sales.created_at")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the code still lack the most important column, the  "outdated_sales" part, that's the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Also `clients.id == sales.client_id` can be removed as it is implied by the `join` and if it is not removed `==` should be `=`.